# Absolute convergence of a power of an absolutely convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum_{i\geq0}a_i$ converges absolutely, ie,
$$
\sum_{i\geq0}\vert a_i\vert<\infty,
$$
what about the series
$$
\sum_{i\geq0}b_i\ :=\left(\sum_{i\geq0}a_i\right)^p,\qquad p\in \mathbb{N},
$$
is it absolutely convergent?

I should prove that:
$$\sum_{i\geq0}\vert b_i\vert<\infty.$$The difficulty is that I can't write $b_i$ explicitly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What series are you talking about. I don't understand your question.

Comment: $\sum b_i$  is it absolutely convergente?

Comment: Define $b_i$. I don't see the definition in your question.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The question makes no sense. Tell us what the n-th term of your new series is.

Comment: The power of an absolutely convergent series is it an absolutely convergent series? This is my question. As regard to $b_i$ I can't define it.

Comment: Maybe you meant the following: given $\sum_{i\geq0}|a_i|<\infty$, then is $\left(\sum_{i\geq0}|a_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$ finite for all $p\in\mathbb{N}$? The answer to that question is yes, as far as I can remember from some standard summation inequalities (like Young's or Holder's)

Comment: @ RMWGNE96, no, I meant, the power of an absolutely convergent series is it an absolutely convergent series

Comment: The power is in the wrong place. You don't want to  calculate $\sum  a_i$ and then take the power.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a well-posed question.

The $b_i$ are not defined in terms of the $a_i$.

Since $\sum a_i$ exists, it is just a constant and can be raised to any power.
Then just define the $b_i$ so they sum to this.

---

(added after the question was edited)

The problem is that
the computation of the
$b_i$
is not specified -
only what
$\sum b_i$
is.

For example,
if you wrote
$\sum_{0 \le i \le n}b_i\ 
:=\left(\sum_{0 \le i \le n}a_i\right)^p
$
then we would know
how to compute the $b_i$
(in this case,
$b_n
=\left(\sum_{0 \le i \le n}a_i\right)^p-\left(\sum_{0 \le i \le n-1}a_i\right)^p
$)
and could try to
answer your question.

But,
until you specify
how to compute
each $b_i$,
there is nothing
we can do.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Still not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{i\geq0}a_i$ converges, there is $s \in \mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{i\geq0}a_i=s.$ Thus

$$\left(\sum_{i\geq0}a_i\right)^p=s^p.$$

Comment: Yes, this is trivial. What about absolute convergence?